# Метод сортирует массив, но максимальный элемент массива пропадает куда-то. Почему?

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

```
void sortAscending() {
    System.out.println("\n\nTask 2.");
    int n = 25;
    int arr[] = new int[n];
    Random r = new Random();
    System.out.println("Initial array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        arr[i] = r.nextInt(100);
        System.out.print(arr[i] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println("\nSorted array ascending:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                int tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(arr[i] + "\t");
    }
}
```

Comment: вот здесь: for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы его просто не выводите, так как `i < n - 1` в

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
```

Добавьте в конце:

```
System.out.print(arr[n - 1] + "\t");
```

Comment: Куда же он пропал....вроде бы был...

Comment: Можно в цикле убрать (n-1), тогда  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i). И не надо выводить System.out.print(arr[n - 1] + "\t");

Comment: `++i`, кто это использует...

Comment: Так производительней. Разве есть особая разница?

Comment: как это можно доказать, что это производительнее? @MishaMickhailov

Comment: "Постфиксный инкремент итератора возвращает предыдущее свое значение для чего используется временная переменная. Для префиксной формы этого не требуется" - Но это не ощутимая разница даже в миллионе итераций. Так что кому как удобней